# Draw image as a continuous-line drawing

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

There is code to drawing  image as a continuous-line

```
tako=Import["http://imgur.com/vJkdS4x.png"]
```

[image]

```
data = ColorQuantize[ColorConvert[tako, "Grayscale"], 2]
pos = PixelValuePositions[ImageAdjust[data], 0];
res = FindShortestTour[pos];
Graphics[Line[pos[[res[[2]]]]]]
```

[image]

but there is intersection points if I zoom it.

[image]

How can I draw it without intersections?

Comment: I can tell you why it happens, but I'm not sure you can easily solve it. From the docs for `FindShortestTour`, "For large datasets, FindShortestTour finds a tour whose length is at least close to the minimum." And "Use `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"` to find an optimal result." However, you've got *way* too many points to solve a [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) optimally on your data. Looking at the intersections you've got you *might* be able to unda a large number of them manually, though.

Comment: see this: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheTravelingSalesmanProblem22OptRemovalOfIntersections/